# How to cite a whitepaper that was removed by vendor's website

Tags: citations

A hardware vendor had released a whitepaper about its product. The document was downloadable through a dynamically generated link, which didn't allow to [save it through the Internet Archive](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49788/citing-a-link-that-was-removed). Moreover, it seems that I can't download the document anymore. I have a (non-watermarked) copy of the document.

How can I effectively cite in my bibliography this document, and possibly make it available?

Comment: Are you sure that the vendor's whitepaper is the only (or best) source for the information you want to cite?

Answer (score 4):

If it is a document you want to publish, then it is best to first check with the journal's policies. Often they advise against citing content that is confidential or non-retrievable for the general public.

You can also try to contact the vendor to make it available to you, 'officially'. You can mention that you want to cite it. You can also ask after an initial correspondence as to why they removed it: this could be mentioned in your article. Perhaps it was not accurate?

You may be able to cite it as personal correspondence.